# How to cleanly set up Angular 2+ components so that they can function as e.g. flex items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In Angular apps, I define component templates like this:

```
<div class="myComponent">
  <div class="myComponent__header"></div>
  <div class="myComponent__body"></div>
</div>
```

I like that this lets me define a class on the root component.

What I *don’t* like is what actually gets rendered:

```
<app-my-component>
  <div class="myComponent">
    <div class="myComponent__header"></div>
    <div class="myComponent__body"></div>
  </div>
</app-my-component>
```

That is, my template gets rendered inside the `<app-my-component>` tag.

I don’t like this because it can have negative effects on my CSS. For example, if I have something like this:

```
.myComponent {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <app-my-component *ngFor="let item in list"></app-my-component>
</div>
```

...the `flex-basis` I declared will have no effect because `.myComponent` is a grandchild of the `display: flex` element, and flex declarations only work on *children* of a `display: flex` element.

If this was Angular.JS I'd use `replace: true`, but that's not available in Angular 2+.

## Solution 1. Use `:host`

Turn my template into:

```
<div class="myComponent__header"></div>
<div class="myComponent__body"></div>
```

And for my SCSS:

```
:host {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

**Issues:** Using `:host` as opposed to an actual CSS class feels hacky. Maybe it's not? But I want to ask the audience.

## Solution 2: Dynamically add a class to the host element

```
constructor(
  hostElement: ElementRef,
) {
  this.hostElement.nativeElement.classList.add('myComponent');
}
```

**Issues:** This feels like a big muddying-up of concerns. Something as generic as using a static CSS class name should be controlled in the HTML, not in the JS.

## Solution 3: Declare the class on the host element

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <app-my-component *ngFor="let item in list" class="myComponent"></app-my-component>
</div>
```

**Issues:** The SCSS for `.myComponent` lives in a separate SCSS file, so unless `ViewEncapsulation` is disabled the CSS won't work.

## Solution 4: Make my component an attribute instead of a tag

```
@Component({
  select: ['my-component']
})
```

```
<div my-component *ngFor="let item in list"></div>
```

**Issues:** The [Angular styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03) doesn't like declaring components as attributes. I can break the rules, but want to make sure I'm not missing an important concept.

## TLDR

I'm probably overthinking this, but I'm new to Angular and really want to understand the Angular way of doing things.

What's the best way to (a) style a host element by (b) using a class? Or is this just not The Angular Way™, and if not, why?

**Edit:** A colleague pointed out that rules like `flex-basis` probably shouldn't be defined on a component's root in the first place, but rather the parent component. So it may be these use-cases I'm worried about never actually occur.

Comment: What is the problem here that you're trying to solve? This reads like a complaint about having to make a decision on your own. Is there something specific that you're having difficulties with?

Comment: You're right that it's me being concerned about making a decision on my own. But I think that's a valid concern, since one of the advantages of using a framework is that it decreases the number of decisions one makes on one's own. If I find myself needing to make a decision about something as generic/fundamental as this, then I suspect I'm not using the framework correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**There is multiple ways recommended by Angular to add class to angular components .**

1) Using `host` property

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: { class: "first-class" }
})
```

2) Using `HostBinding`

`@HostBinding('class') class = 'second-class';`

3) Using `Renderer2`

```
 constructor(private renderer:Renderer2,private elementRef:ElementRef) { 
    this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement,"third-class");
  }
```

[Check this in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-styling)

You can define the styles globally , no need for disabling the view encapsulation.